# Umbraco how to Bind Navigation using asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, umbraco, umbraco7

I just start to work with Umbraco 7, 
I created 2 Documents type and 3 pages,

i'm using an templeate which i download from the starter kit..

first of all, why it is so difficult to understand this platform?!?! 
i saw all of the clips in Umbraco.tv already..

second and the important question is: 
why the navigation bar doesn't show me all the pages? it seems that i have only 1 page which is hard coded already..

Here is the template's code:

```
@inherits UmbracoTemplatePage
@{
    // Model.Content is the current page that we're on AncestorsOrSelf is all of the ancestors this page has in the tree
    // (1) means: go up to level 1 and stop looking for more ancestors when you get there First() gets the first ancestor found (the home page, on level 1)
    var homePage = CurrentPage.AncestorsOrSelf(1).First();
    var menuItems = homePage.Children.Where("UmbracoNaviHide == false");
}
<!-- Nav -->
<ul class="menu">
    @* If the Url of the current page is "/" then we want to add the class "current_page_item" *@
    @* Otherwise, we set the class to null, that way it will not even be added to the <li> element *@
    <li class="@(CurrentPage.Url == "/" ? "sel" : null)">
        <a href="/homepage">Home</a>
    </li>
    @foreach (var item in menuItems)
    {
        var childrenItems = item.Children.Where("UmbracoNaviHide == false");
        <li class="@(CurrentPage.Id == item.Id ? "sel" : null)">
            <a href="@item.Url">@item.Name</a>
            @createSubmenu(childrenItems, item.Id)
        </li>
    }
</ul>

@helper createSubmenu(IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> nodes, int? parentId) {
    if (nodes.Count() > 0){
        <ul>
        @foreach (var node in nodes)
        {
            var childrenItems = node.Children.Where("UmbracoNaviHide == false");
            <li class="@(CurrentPage.Id == node.Id ? "sel" : null)">
                <a href="@node.Url">@node.Name</a>
                @createSubmenu(childrenItems, node.Id)
            </li>
        }
        </ul>
    }
}
<!-- /Nav -->
```

Comment: Please try like this 
var menuItems = homePage.Children.Where(x.GetPropertyValue("umbracoNaviHide")=="1"); and modify the code with .Where(x.GetPropertyValue("umbracoNaviHide")=="1") where ever you have used .Where("UmbracoNaviHide == false").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Umbraco is so hard (it's not) because it's a platform that takes all it's glory when a developper uses it. What I mean by that is that many people expect the product to be an "out-of-the-box" website, that you can install a theme then edit the content. That's Wordpress. Umbraco is not like that. It has some starter kits, I don't find that they help all that much. When I build an Umbraco site, I always start from a blank slate.
2. Now you are trying to print your nav menu from what I see. Here is the code I reccomend using for this. Also, you'll want to consider using a master template, that will have your navigation.

   `<ul>
       @{
           var homeNode = Model.Content.AncestorOrSelf("[HomeNodeDocumentType]");
       }
       @foreach (var node in homeNode.Children.Where(x => x.IsVisible))
       {
           <li>
               <a href="@node.Url">@node.AsDynamic().yourFieldForTheTitle</a>
           </li>
       }
   </ul>`

Some key points:

- The previous code you had was for multi-level menus, you can rewrite the code I supplied for that if needed. I find not a lot need that.
- Notice the "yourFieldForTheTitle", that's a custom textstring you must add to your document type, don't use Name, it'll cause you headaches down the road.
- Notice the "[HomeNodeDocumentType]" document type. When traversing the tree, use those to navigate quickly to the node you want.
- Finally, get your Umbraco site setup with Visual Studio, the Intellisense will help you get started.

That's about it! Umbraco is so good, stick with it and it'll be worth your while!